# Load data, multiple files into hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, partition

I want to load data from multiple files stored in a single directory into a partitioned table using spark. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: what kind of files? do you mean like `spark.read.csv`?

Comment: What kind of partitioning? RDD partitioning, parquet partitioning?

Comment: I'm talking about csv files.. and for partitioning, I would like to know about both - RDD and parquet and please suggest which will be better.